# .NET User Control Event Bubbling

Tags: c#, asp.net

By folllowing [this example](http://odetocode.com/articles/94.aspx), I was trying to raise an event at user control level and then bubble it up to the aspx code behind. However, it seems the public event was never attached (or always null) and therefore it never bubbles up. My code goes as follows:

```
// WebUserControl1.ascx
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="testEventeventBubbling.WebUserControl1" %>
<div>       
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>

// WebUserControl1.ascx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("WebUserControl1 :: Page_Load <BR>");
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("WebUserControl1 :: Begin Button1_Click <BR>");
    OnBubbleClick(e);
    Response.Write("WebUserControl1 :: End Button1_Click <BR>");
}

public event EventHandler BubbleClick;

protected void OnBubbleClick(EventArgs e)
{
    // BubbleClick is always null at this point
    if (BubbleClick != null)
    {
        BubbleClick(this, e);
    }
}   

// Default.aspx
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="testEventeventBubbling._Default" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="wuc" TagName="BubbleControl" Src="WebUserControl1.ascx" %>
...
<wuc:BubbleControl id="BubbleControl1" runat="server" />

// Default.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BubbleControl1.BubbleClick += new EventHandler(BubbleControl1_BubbleClick);
}

void BubbleControl1_BubbleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track but don't know if I missed anything obvious or stupid. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why do you want server-side events to bubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BubbleClick is always null because you haven't assigned any event handlers to the event.

Comment: In the Page_Load event, I added the following: this.BubbleClick += new EventHandler(Button1_Click); and it seems to work. Is this the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I would not say it's improper but usually you want to declare the event handler in the ASPX instead of the code-behind, so OnBubbleClick="Button1_Click". Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your problem but failed.
Are you sure this is the exact code you are trying to use? For me the event handler gets assigned seamlessly in `Page_Load` and `BubbleControl1_BubbleClick` gets executed.